# How to delete resources by label with Kubeclient?

Tags: ruby, kubernetes, configmap

I am trying to delete multiple ConfigMaps at once using a label. With `kubectl`, I would do it as follow:

```sh
kubectl delete cm -l application=my-app
```

Kubeclient offers the `delete_config_map` method, but it requires a name.

```rb
# `k` is an instance of Kubeclient::Client
k.delete_config_map('my-config-map')
```

---

**Is there a way to acheive the same behavior as the CLI here?**

Comment: If you run `kubectl --v=10` or so, you'll observe that `delete -l application=my-app` actually does two operations: `get -o name cm -l ...` followed by `delete $(those names)`, which is the same action you'll have to do manually via the API

Comment: Yeah, I figured as much when I realized that even the API didn't offer this feature. Thanks for the tip about `--v=10`, though, it's really helpful! Feel free to turn your commment into an answer, I'll gladly accept it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way `kubectl` does operations upon labeled, versus named, resources is that it actually does that in two phases: `get -o name $resourceType -l ...` and then the actual requested operation upon `${those_resource_names}`

One can run `kubectl --v=10` (or the `v` of your choice) to see it in action

Since that behavior is a feature of `kubectl` and not the kubernetes API itself, it means anyone trying to replicate that handy feature will need to replicate the two-phase approach also